# 8086 Assembly, Array values aren't properly set

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have a problem with the code I've written. I kept getting an infinite loop in the toggle_process subprocedure, but it seems that I've resolved the issue. The issue I have now is that the values in the cups array should either be 0 or 1, but are displaying dummy values like 53248.
The objective of this assignment is to move a marble into a cup, "represented by a 1", or remove the marble if there is one there already. First pass is 1-500, second pass are multiplies of 2, third pass for multiples of 3, and so on.

My apologies if the the answer is obvious. My professor hasn't taught the class all semester so I've been bruteforceing every assignment. I appreciate any help.

```
;===================================================================
;       Marbles Program
;   Purpose: This Program program displays the prime numbers 
;   between 1-500.
;                 
;===================================================================
        DOSSEG
        .MODEL SMALL,BASIC
        .486
;===================================================================
        INCLUDE PCMAC.inc
        EXTRN GETDEC$:FAR           ;GET 16-BIT DECIMAL INTEGER
        EXTRN NEWLINE:FAR           ;DISPLAY NEWLINE CHARACTER
    EXTRN PUTDEC$:FAR           ;DISPLAY 16-BIT DECIMAL INTEGER
        EXTRN PUTSTRNG:FAR          ;DISPLAY CHARACTER STRING
    EXTRN PAUSE:FAR             ;PAUSES SCREEN
    EXTRN PUTBIN:FAR
;===================================================================
;
; S T A C K   S E G M E N T   D E F I N I T I O N
;
           .STACK 1000H
;===================================================================
;
; C O N S T A N T   S E G M E N T   D E F I N I T I O N
;
           .CONST
header  DB  'Marble Problem.';15
prog_by DB  'Programmed by';29
comma   DB  ',';2
;===================================================================
;       Data Segment Definition
        .Data
cups        DB  500 dup(?)  ;cup with marble = 1,empty = 0
count1      DW  0
count2      DW  0
temp        DW  0
;===================================================================
; C O D E   S E G M E N T   D E F I N I T I O N
        .CODE Main
        .Startup
        push ds
        pop es
;
    ;call initialize
    call toggle_process
    call print_ 
    call newline
    call newline
    lea di,prog_by
    mov cx,29
    call putstrng
    mov cx,0
    call pause
    .exit
;
toggle_process proc near public
    pushf
    mov count1,0
;
_outer:
    add count1,1
    mov count2,0
_inner:
    add count2,1
    call get_index
    mov al,[cups + bx]
    call set_cups
    mov [cups + bx],al
    cmp count2,500
    jne _inner
;
    cmp count1,500
    jne _outer
    popf
    ret
toggle_process endp
;
get_index proc near public
    mov ax,count1
    mov bx,count2
    mul bx
    mov bx,ax
    dec bx
    ret
get_index endp
;
set_cups proc near public uses ax
    pushf
    .if al == 0
        mov al,1
        mov ah,0
    .else
        mov al,0
        mov ah,0
    .endif
    popf
    ret
set_cups endp
;
print_ proc near public
    pushf
    mov bx,0
    mov count1,0
print:
    add count1,1
    mov bx,count1
    dec bx
    mov al,[cups + bx]
    mov bx,0
    mov bl,-1
    call putdec$
    .if count1 != 500
        lea di,comma
        push cx
        mov cx,1
        call putstrng
        pop cx
    .endif
    cmp count1,500
    jne print
    popf
    ret
print_ endp
end
```

Comment: 500 times 500 is more than 500.

Comment: So what happens when you step through your code using a debugger?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer : What's a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those **dummy values like 53248** stem from the fact that you are reading from memory that you didn't declare as part of your *cups* array and because in your *print_* procedure you neglect to zero AH prior to calling *putdec$* which expects a 16-bit value.

Because both *count* variables have values ranging from 1 to 500 the zero-based index you calculate in *get_index* can get as large as 24999. This index is used to reference the much smaller *cups* array!
Solve this issue by writing:

```
cups        DB  25000 dup(?)  ;cup with marble = 1,empty = 0
```

You could of course keep the 500 cups and go for good combinations of both counters.

```
cmp count2,50
jne _inner
cmp count1,10
jne _outer
```

or

```
cmp count2,25
jne _inner
cmp count1,20
jne _outer
```

or

```
cmp count2,5
jne _inner
cmp count1,100
jne _outer
```

or

```
...
```